# Trigger for auto-generated DataGrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, datagrid

I currently work on a WPF project which handels data within an auto-generated data grid. How can I set up a trigger, for changing the background color of a column depending on an empty textbox?

My current usercontrol XAML creates a grid which keeps and data grid inside. For each DataGridColumnHeader I set a new ContentTemplate, which keeps a TextBlock (for the actual header) and a TextBox for filtering.

I tried to set up a trigger for DataGridCell, which worked, but only changes the color of the cell. I can't find a specific target type for a data grid column.

```
<UserControl x:Class="...">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColums="True" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="MyDataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="x:Type DataGridColumnHeader=">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="myBlock" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                <TextBox x:Name="myBox" KeyUp="KeyUpEvent" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I expect to change the color of a data grid column, if the TextBox is filled with content. Currently I do not know how to set a specific trigger for a data grid column, if the column are auto-generated. 
**EDIT #1:** Something like that:

[image: DataGrid with columns, rows and filter cell beneath column name]

This is when the data grid doesn't have any filters set. But the appearance changes, as soon as you enter a filter text inside one of the filters, like that:

[image: DataGrid with one filter set in the second column]

**EDIT #2:**

I was able to build a solution for coloring the rows programmatically, without coloring the header. That's missing. Do you have any suggestions?

See the following code:

```
private void StyleRows(string text, string name)
{
    if(text != "" && column != "")
    {
        foreach(DataGridColumn column in DataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if(column.Header == column)
            {
                Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
                style.Settes.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red));
                column.cellStyle = style
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to do that inside the XAML?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way to do it in XAML only**.

You could try to **adjust a ViewModel** to provide for each column whether the content of `TextBox` is empty or not(bind the `TextBox.Text` to the properties and provide `bool` properties to check string is null or empty). But it's also not a *"XAML only"* solution.

If yoy set the `CellStyle` you will need to observe the control from template and use trigger, but you have no access to it.

I would do it with a `Behavior`. Once you have written a `Behavior` you can easily **use/reuse it in XAML only** without need to touch/adjust a code behind.

```
public class ObserveEmpty : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public Control TargetControl
    {
        get { return (Control)GetValue(TargetControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetControlProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetControl), typeof(object), typeof(ObserveEmpty), new PropertyMetadata(null, TargetCtlChanged));

    private static void TargetCtlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as ObserveEmpty)?.SetTargetBackground();
    }
    public Brush TargetBgrndBrushOnEmpty { get; set; }
    public Brush TargetBgrndBrush { get; set; }


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        SetTargetBackground();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += AssociatedObject_TextChanged;
    }
    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= AssociatedObject_TextChanged;
    }
    private void AssociatedObject_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetTargetBackground();
    }
    private void SetTargetBackground()
    {
        if (TargetControl != null)
        {
            var brush = string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssociatedObject?.Text) ? TargetBgrndBrushOnEmpty : TargetBgrndBrush;

            TargetControl.Background = brush;

            var dgrClmnHdr = TargetControl as DataGridColumnHeader;
            if (dgrClmnHdr?.Column != null)
            {
                Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
                style.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, brush));
                dgrClmnHdr.Column.CellStyle = style;
            }
        }
    }
}

xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="myBlock" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="myBox">
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <local:ObserveEmpty TargetBgrndBrush="Aqua" TargetBgrndBrushOnEmpty="Red" 
                                                        TargetControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: I have made some changes and edits. Only changing the background color of the DataGridColumnHeader isn't all (look at the pictures). I was able to set the background color of the rows programmically, but actually I wanted to do that via the XAML file. And, in addition to that, I wanted to change the DataGridColumnHeader background as well.